# Why is this PDF not cropped tightly?

Tags: tikz-pgf, xetex, crop, pdfcrop, hobby

Here is my MWE, adapted with cosmetic changes from Andre Stacey's [hobby package](https://ctan.org/pkg/hobby?lang=en), which I compiled with `xelatex`:

```
\documentclass[crop]{standalone}
\PassOptionsToPackage{cmyk,svgnames,dvipsnames,hyperref}{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[use Hobby shortcut, every path/.style={line width=2mm, Gold, double=MidnightBlue, double distance=1mm}]
\draw ([closed]0,2) .. ([blank=soft]210:0.5) .. (-30:2) ..([blank=soft]0,0.5) .. (210:2) .. ([blank=soft]-30:0.5);
\draw[use previous Hobby path={invert soft blanks,disjoint}];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The resulting PDF is cropped tightly at the top but has non-zero margins/borders at the other three sides. Please click on image below to see this:

[image: Trefoil with non-zero borders on three sides.]

Can some please explain why this is so and suggest how to correct it please?

The problem may be resolved by separately applying `pdfcrop` to the PDF but I would like to solve the issue at source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download the `bbox` library from [here](https://github.com/marmotghost/tikz-bbox) and use it.

```
\documentclass[crop]{standalone}
\PassOptionsToPackage{cmyk,svgnames,dvipsnames,hyperref}{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{bbox,hobby}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[bezier bounding box,use Hobby shortcut, every path/.style={line width=2mm, Gold, double=MidnightBlue, double distance=1mm}]
\draw ([closed]0,2) .. ([blank=soft]210:0.5) .. (-30:2) ..([blank=soft]0,0.5) .. (210:2) .. ([blank=soft]-30:0.5);
\draw[use previous Hobby path={invert soft blanks,disjoint}];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The reason why you see the extra space is that Ti*k*Z computes the bounding box from the control points of curves, and not from the curve.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation and solution. It works. I have installed it in `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex/tikz-bbox/`.

If the library author and the CTAN folk have no objection, I would recommend adding this to the CTAN repository so that installation and location on the CTAN tree are automatic and hassle-free.

Please add my vote for this.